# .net +oracle error

Tags: asp.net, exception, ado.net, oracle10g, .net-2.0

I am using ASP.NET 2.0 (Visual Studio 2005) and Oracle 10g database

my application do not have build errors.Build is succeeded.

But i am getting run time error.

The below thing is the error which is i am getting.

> Exception Details: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'OraOps10w.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Please help me in this.

Comment: Please rename your question - give it more meaningful title.

Answer (score 0):

The assembly OraOps10w.dll is not referenced in your project (which is probably ok like that), and so it compiles ok.
But at runtime, any referenced Oracle assemblies most likely call in their turn the OraOps10w.dll, which they cannot find at the location of the running assembly.

I suspect you copied the Oracle assembly you needed for compilation (typically the Oracle.DataAccess.dll), while you should reference it at its original location (namely, the Oracle HOME installation directory).

edit: Very similar question to [NHibernate Oracle - Unable to load DLL 'OraOps10w.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821076/nhibernate-oracle-unable-to-load-dll-oraops10w-dll)

As is mentioned in an answer to that question, you could install the Oracle XEClient (free download, around 20MB), and reference the Oracle.DataAccess.dll in that location.  Keep in mind that you'll have to install this package on each client in order to work !

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Data Provider needs theses dlls : Oracle.DataAccess.dll and OraOps11w.dll

add reference to Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Comment: Tahnks for reply.....I am having Oracle.DataAccess.dll(1.102.3.0) version.This dll is in oracle10g folder.But i don't have OraOps11w.dll.From where i can get that dll.

Comment: odp.net4/bin, Follow this forum in order to resolve your problem : http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/blogs/connect-to-an-oracle-database-without-an-oracle-client.aspx